# Fill in an ndarray1 with columns from ndarray2 while skipping certain column index in ndarray1

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am hoping to fill in the columns of a new array with columns from an old array while skipping certain predefined columns from the new array.

The old array:

```
x_old = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

The new array is defined as a zero array:

```
x_new = np.zeros((3,5))
```

I wish to copy the columns from x_old to x_news while skipping column '0' & column '2' in the new array, so the new array would look like:

```
x_new = np.array([[0,1,0,2,3],[0,4,0,5,6],[0,7,0,8,9]])
```

Here are the codes I wrote to automate this process:

```
numcol = len(x_old[0])
columns_to_skip = [0,2]
c, s = 0, 0
while s < numcol:
    if c in columns_to_skip:
        x_full[:, c+1] = x_old[:,s]
        s, c = s+1, c+1
    else:
        x_full[:,c] = x_old[:,s]
        s, c = s+1, c+1
```

The results failed to copy the first column (column '0' using Python index, or `[1,4,7].T`) to the new array and only kept the second & third columns (`[2,5,6]` & `[3,6,9]`). I cannot find what went wrong with the codes.

Also, is there a faster way to do this?

THANKS SO MUCH for any help. I am new to Python and got stuck!

Comment: You mean just do: `x_new[:,[1,3,4]] = x_old`?

Comment: Yes. Your way is better, and it echoes the answer given by sacul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
columns_to_skip = [0,2]
columns_to_use = np.delete(np.arange(x_new.shape[1]), columns_to_skip)

x_new[:, columns_to_use] = x_old
```

Which gives:

```
>>> x_new
array([[0., 1., 0., 2., 3.],
       [0., 4., 0., 5., 6.],
       [0., 7., 0., 8., 9.]])
```

An alternative to this strategy might be to just insert `0` columns into your `x_old` array, at your desired locations:

```
x_new = np.insert(x_old, [0,1], 0, 1)
>>> x_new
array([[0, 1, 0, 2, 3],
       [0, 4, 0, 5, 6],
       [0, 7, 0, 8, 9]])
```

## How to fix your loop

If you are attached to your loop method, you can achieve the same by doing:

```
numcol = len(x_old[0])
columns_to_skip = [0,2]
c, s = 0, 0

while s < numcol:
    if c in columns_to_skip:
        c = c+1
    else:
        x_new[:,c] = x_old[:,s]
        s, c = s+1, c+1

>>> x_new
array([[0., 1., 0., 2., 3.],
       [0., 4., 0., 5., 6.],
       [0., 7., 0., 8., 9.]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works great. But I still wonder what went wrong with those tedious codes I wrote... anyway I like your approach better!

Comment: Fabulous! Thank you so much!!